# Fix hyperlink to the right

Tags: html

I have a php file which will display a list of data which need to be scrolled down to be viewed fully.

To create hyperlink, I used the following:

```
<a href="http://localhost/test.php">Click here to go to main page</a>
```

How do I create a hyperlink that will stay fixed at the right while the user scroll down to view the data so that user need not scroll up again to click the hyperlink?

Comment: I don't think that PHP is relevant at all here. You're asking about the HTML that your PHP script generates.

Comment: Yes, sorry removed php tag already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this

```
<div style="background-color:#eee; border:#ddd 1px solid; position:fixed; top:400px; right:0; padding:20px;"><a href="http://localhost/test.php">Click here to go to main page</a></div>
```

now you can adjust `top:` and `right`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS positioning

```
position: fixed;



a
{
position: fixed;
}
```